# How to get freewins plugin working in compiz?

Tags: 10.10, compiz

How do I get the newest version of freewins compiz plugin working?

It comes in a folder, but it has no Makefile?

I am trying to get a nice multitouch compiz working, and to do so, I need this plugin.

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag explaining that.

Comment: It's a cool (but not very useful) plugin. Last time I tried it (which was years ago) it was buggy.

Comment: http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Freewins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is not longer supported, and when was being developed was very very buggy, and would cause a total system freeze. It also does not support input redirection, so if you rotate a window, the window becomes useless for anything but looking at it.

I would suggest you not use it. Unity has grab handles now, and Ubuntu 11.04 and up supports multitouch, so if you use multitouch, rely on Unity in 11.04+ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed all experimental plug-ins from this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/install-compiz-experimental-plugins-in.html), and i get it to work well

[image: compiz freewins]

---

[image: freewins effect1]

---

[image: freewins effect2]