# How to rotate a specific window in 90ْ ​​?

Tags: window-manager

Is there a way to rotate a specific window and not the whole screen?

Comment: Maybe the Compiz Configuration offers an option to rotate a window

Answer (score 1):

The [Freewins](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Freewins) plugin for compiz is supposed to be able to do that.

The support status of the plugin is a bit unclear. It can be installed by typing `apt-get install compiz-plugins`, but for a long time I could not figure out how to get it to do anything other than cause selected windows to "permanently" lose focus until compiz is restarted.

An [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/82692/284919) from three years ago says it is no longer supported and recommends not using it as it could cause system freezes. It recommends an alternative which supports some of the features of Freewins, but unfortunately not window rotation.

In my experience compiz freezes can happen even without installing this plugin, but when they do happen the system can be unfrozen by ssh to the machine and running `DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace`. I do not know if the freezes that Freewins allegedly cause are any harder to fix than those which can happen in a standard compiz install. So far I haven't seen it cause a problem that could not be fixed by restarting compiz.

If you want to give that plugin a try, I recommend your first learn how to restart compiz remotely, in case you should need to do so. Secondly I recommend you disable the two options `Prevent Input` and `Immediate Moves`, as those seem to be causing the most trouble.

Additionally, there is a setting deciding which windows are allowed to be rotated. I haven't figured out exactly how it works, but it appears that "old-skool" applications such as xterm cannot be rotated.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> can be used to rotate the window in focus. <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> will return to normal orientation (though sometimes I had to press it a few times before it worked).

I couldn't get rotation by using the mouse to work at all. And a rotated window could not be focused using the mouse, but it could be selected using <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate a certain window, press shift+ctrl then drag on the window you want to rotate. But, this method could cause shadow glitches, the rotated window appearing as a square in the switch window GUI, slowness and possibly your computer freezing.

Answer (score -1):

I know of a "cheating" way to do it, one screenshot at a time...

1. Grab a screenshot (<kbd>Print Scrn</kbd>)
2. Open screenshot in GIMP (or the default viewer if it can do 3.)
3. Rotate image 90ْ

And `vlc` can rotate a video to any angle you want. If you could get `vlc` to open only part of your Desktop (in Capture Device) you might be able to rotate it's display to see a "live" view of the window too...